# How to wait till System.Diagnostics.Process.Start is finished

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running a command line argument from code behind that runs an executable. The problem is the executable is supposed to create a csv file from a binary file which works fine except i need to move the file when the process is finished. The question i have is how to know when the process finishes. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(hexFilePath, filepath + " B");//This creates csv
```

Need to have some sort of mechanism here to wait till Process is finished.

```
File.Move(filepath, archiveDirectory);//This is where i move the binary file to archive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var p = Process.Start((hexFilePath, filepath +" B");//This creates csv
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Yep that worked thanks so much.

Comment: will verify in 8 minutes